# Solid transparent line in WPF gradient

Tags: wpf, xaml, gradient

I am trying to draw a transparent line in a solid block using a gradient:

```
<Grid>
    <Border Margin="-102,-27,102,27">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="517,160" StartPoint="0,160" MappingMode="Absolute">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF2DBCF2" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF2DBCF2" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#002DBCF2" Offset="0.0091" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF2DBCF2" Offset="0.009"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#002DBCF2" Offset="0.015"/>

                <GradientStop Color="#FF2DBCF2" Offset="0.0151"/>

            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that on the edges of the gap in the solid colour block there is a faint fading effect which makes the edge slightly less than crisp. Is there a way to get rid of this faint fading? I just can't seem to find a way around it.

[image: Gradient Zoomed in]

Comment: this is what gradients *do*. they're not supposed to draw sharp lines

Comment: Photoshop and CSS3 are both able to accomplish this. I realize it is a slightly off-label use but it will make my UI much simpler if I can get it to work this way @TimothyGroote

Comment: The problem with your gradient, is that it stretches to accomodate the size of the border.
No matter how sharp you define the change between the colors, if the border becomes wide enough, it will show blurry lines

Comment: Isn't that what the absolute mapping mode is for @TimothyGroote?

Comment: It is true that the absolute mapping mode is intended to fix a gradient on absolute distances, rather than stretching it across the size of the parent, but a gradient is still a gradient, and WPF will even try to calculate and present gradients on a sub-pixel level ( see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058.aspx )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use something like the following `DrawingBrush` for the background:

```
<Border Margin="-102,-27,102,27">
    <Border.Background>
        <DrawingBrush>
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF2DBCF2">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <GeometryGroup>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,0.01,1"/>
                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0.015,0,0.985,1"/>
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get a sharp line in the background is to use an `ImageBrush` or `DrawingBrush` as background instead of a `LinearGradientBrush`

I can't work out a complete example right now, but this should get you started on how to implement a `DrawingBrush` as background.

```
<Border.Background>
    <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Stretch="None" Viewport="0,0,20,20" ViewportUnits="Absolute">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <GeometryDrawing>
                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    <Pen Brush="White"/>
                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                    <LineGeometry StartPoint="0.3,0"
                                  EndPoint="0.3,20"/>
                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
<Border.Background>
```